# VLC is installed but doesn't run properly

Tags: vlc

I've had made a huge mistake by wiping out every VLC folder from Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to reinstall it, but it doesn't work.
I tried installing it by command line and it seems to work: however, when I run the `vlc` command, it says VLC is not installed.
If I try to install it again, it tells me VLC is already at the latest version.
Now I can't run VLC any more and can't figure how to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

I ran these:

```
sudo apt-get remove -f --purge vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

And then these:

```
sudo apt-get install -f vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

Apparently everything gets back to normal. Even the icons got back.
Now I finally am able to run `vlc` on the terminal and get some response. Unfortunatey I still am not able to make it run properly, VLC does not open by any chance. This pops up:

```
VLC media player 2.0.5 Twoflower (revision 2.0.5-0-g1661b7d) 

The remote control interface was started. Type 'help' for help.
```

However, not a single window opens.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get autoremove vlc`?

Comment: Yes I have. It is removed and I am able to install it again but it doesn't start anyway. The vlc is not installed message keeps showing and vlc keeps not running.

Comment: Try checking the official website for VLC.
Here's a link: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Delete the VLC profile

**Deleting the profile folder of VLC makes it work as when you first installed it.**

### Using terminal

1. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
2. Run `rm -rf .config/vlc/`

### Using GUI

1. Go to Home folder
2. Show hidden files (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)
3. Open the folder **.config**
4. Right click on vlc folder and delete
5. Restart VLC and see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting issue you have there... Have you tried

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc --purge
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I've already tried and yet no positive response.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with deleting all folders that find in my Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64. Following the steps above, installing it and now it is running well. 
I saw that there is a mistake in the following line 
$sudo apt-get remove -f --purge vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notigy vlc-plugin-pulse

(vlc-plugin-notigy) must be vlc-plugin-notify

```
$sudo apt-get remove -f --purge vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

And then, ran these

```
$sudo apt-get install -f vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notigy vlc-plugin-pulse browser-plugin-vlc
```

I am using firefox browser, and need the browser plugging, last one is sugested in the vlc website.

Comment: It was most likely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to completely remove vlc by applying these commands:

**Remove VLC Completely**

1. > rm -rf .config/vlc/
2. > sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc

---

Now, you have to by applying these commands:

**Install snap/snapd**

1. > sudo apt install snap
2. > sudo apt install snapd

---

**Install vlc from Ubuntu Software Center only...**

**!!Dont from terminal!!**

[Install VLC from here](https://snapcraft.io/vlc)

---

**Now open vlc and it will be run...**